# PYTHON : Error while indexing an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of dictionaries. I have no problem when I try to access the value of a single element A[0] even when indexing a value of the dictionary A[0]['MAX'].
I can index a range of values A[0:2] or A[0:]. But if I try to access the dictionary value for a range of values of A A[0:2]['MAX'] I get the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I was trying to make a histogram with matplotlib plt.hist(A[:]['MAX'], 100) from command line.
As an example from command line:

> data[0]

> {'ATTR': '{"CLASS": "CARRAY", "CurrentOffset": 90, "Day": 23, "Dec": 1, "Eql": 1, "HH": 0, "Month": 6, "PPSSliceNO": 0,
> "SampleNo": 16384, "TITLE": "wf_0", "TimeSts": 0, "TriggerOffset":
> 1288, "VERSION": "2.0", "Year": 122, "configID": 0, "mm": 17, "rp_id":
> 2, "runid": 101, "sessionID": 0, "ss": 50, "tend": 1658535455.2211432,
> "tstart": 1658535455.221012, "usec": 475094}', 'WFM': 'wf_000000',
> 'START': 0, 'END': 16384, 'MAX': array([45.90404102]), 'INTEGRAL':
> 1912.7090709314268, 'ToT': 2, 'Base': -55987.730435841775, 'DATA': array([[-7.32511293],
> [-7.56928336],
> [-7.56928336],
> ...,
> [-6.22634599],
> [-5.24966427],
> [-6.71468685]])}

No problem indexing single values:

> data[0]['START']

> 0

> data[0]['MAX']

> array([45.90404102])
> If I type data[0:2] I will get a list of all values in that range

But if I try to gat a list of all 'START' values:

> data[:]['START']

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Can you please add the dictionary with the question?

Comment: `A[0]['MAX']` should give you whatever is stored there, like a float for example. What type of output do you expect from `A[:]['MAX']`? A list? If so, you could try `[item['MAX'] for item in A]`

Comment: Sounds like you want to stuff this into a dataframe

Comment: as an example:>>> data[0:2]
[{'ATTR': '{"CLASS": "CARRAY", "CurrentOffset": 90, "Day": 23, "Dec": 1, "Eql": 1, "HH": 0, "Month": 6, "PPSSliceNO": 0, "SampleNo": 16384, "TITLE": "wf_0", "TimeSts": 0, "TriggerOffset": 1288, "VERSION": "2.0", "Year": 122, "configID": 0, "mm": 17, "rp_id": 2, "runid": 101, "sessionID": 0, "ss": 50, "tend": 1658535455.2211432, "tstart": 1658535455.221012, "usec": 475094}', 'WFM': 'wf_000000', 'START': 0, 'END': 16384, 'MAX': array([45.90404102]), 'INTEGRAL': 1912.7090709314268, 'ToT': 2, 'Base': -55987.730435841775, 'DATA': array([[-7.32511293],...

Comment: Please edit the original question with the example. Its best if its in a form that we can copy, run, and get a result.

Comment: To format code, data and Tracebacks select it and type `ctrl-k`. You have used *quote* formatting -  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A[0:2]` is a list. `[a['MAX'] for a in A]` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're getting a list of dictionaries back from A[0:2]
And list indices can only be slices (0:2, or 1:3) or ints

You could use list comprehension to get the values of a indivisual dictionary and add it to a list.

I'm not so sure about this but i think this would work:

```
values = [i['MAX'] for i in A[:2] if True]
```

Answer (score 0):

`A[0:2]` returns a list of dictionaries unlike `A[0]` which returns a dictionary.

You cannot index an array with your string 'MAX' however you can with the dictionary. As mentioned in other answers you want to loop over `A[0:2]` in some matter to get the maximum of each dictionary.